# ROS Driver for Keyence SZ-16D safety Sensor

Tags: lidar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Everyone,
I am working on a **Keyence 2D Lidar  SZ-16D**. The LIDAR communicates with the computer through RS-422A interface. I was wondering if someone has already written the ROS driver for it.

If not I would like to write one, it would be really great if someone with a experience of ROS driver development(for lidars)experience could show me the direction. Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200563/ros-driver-for-keyence-sz-16d-safety-sensor/) by [metal](https://answers.ros.org/users/1575/metal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 174 on 2015-01-07

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [glwz](https://answers.ros.org/users/32747/glwz/) on 2017-11-24**:
Hi, can you confirm us what you do with Keyence 2D Lidar SZ-16D driver? are you test it using velodyne driver? thanks for your contribution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Another example of a nice (at least, I've always thought so) example of a driver for Lidars is the [velodyne](http://wiki.ros.org/velodyne) package by @joq.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not sure if this helps, but have you thought about [urg_node](http://wiki.ros.org/urg_node)?

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2015-01-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1